# How can I disable my user-login-block?

Tags: drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7.51. I've changed the block status to --none--, but it is still out there.That is very strange.

Comment: What theme are you using? are you sure it's a block that is providing that specific login form? You need to provide more information in order to receive an answer.

Comment: I am using DataPublic theme. I've tried change my theme. But it does't make any change.

Answer (score 0):

By "block status" I am assuming you are talking about the block's placement on `/admin/structure/block`.

If the block is turned off there, there are only a few other usual ways to place the block.

1. Context
2. Panels
3. Some other module like LoginToboggan that creates a replacement block.

I'd check those three to make sure they aren't affecting anything.

Turn off those modules if they are on and flush your caches to see if the block disappears.

The block could also be created by a custom module if you have any of those.

If none of that helps, use your browser's inspector to see if there are any clues around the block code to indicate what might be providing the block.